# Knowing if a page is already liked on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if the user already like the page in Facebook Likebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357427/how-to-know-if-the-user-already-like-the-page-in-facebook-likebox)

Is there a way to know if a user likes the current page WITHOUT using asking the user for permissions?

The page has a like button and I am using the javascript to figure out when this button is clicked to show hidden content. However when the page is refreshed the button is shown as "liked" but the hidden content is still hidden.

Is there a javascript to know if the state of the facebook button is "Liked"?

Comment: Check out my answer on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4357427/how-to-know-if-the-user-already-like-the-page-in-facebook-likebox - this should work for any app on a page tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a javascript to know if the state of the Facebook button is
>   "Liked" *without app authorization/authentication* on my web page (**not** FB page tab)?

**NO**, this is not possible.